# Does laptop Embedded Controller have limited writes?

Tags: hardware

I am wondering if I should be worried about excessive writes to the embedded controller registers on my laptop. I am guessing that if they are true registers, they probably act more like RAM rather than flash memory so this isn't a problem.

However, I have a script to modify the registers in my laptop's EC to better control the fan speed curve. It has to be re-applied after each power change event such as sleep/wake as well as power cable events, so it happens fairly often. I just want to make sure I am not burning out my chips in the process.

The script I am using to write to the EC is located here:
https://github.com/RayfenWindspear/perl-acpi-fanspeed

Comment: "embedded controller registers" What are you referring to? I might not be the optimal person to ask, but this sounds incredibly vague. Which controller are we talking about? Your laptop probably has about 200 chips that have registers that you can write to.

Comment: To be honest, I am not quite sure. I will edit in a link to my GitHub repository for the script that does the manipulation.

Comment: anyway, if you're doing a write on every laptop close, open, reboot, I think your laptop's display joints will be worn out before anything that is at least an EEPROM shows degradation.

Comment: That is probably true enough. I actually just remembered I was writing a line to a log file each time the script is run. I posted the script 5 months ago and my log file only had 500 lines in it. Still, if it is one of those 10,000 writes chips, which is doubtful, I would like to know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems you're writing to ACPI registers. Registers here do not refer to any specific hardware; it just means its a specific address that you can reach using a specific bus. It's however highly unlikely that something that you have to re-write after every power cycle is overwriting permanent storage, so for all practical aspects I'd assume that you can rely on this for as long as your laptop lives.

Answer (score 1):

Hardware peripherals are almost universally implemented as SRAM cells.  They will not wear out **first**.  The fan you are controlling will have a limited number of start/stop cycles.  So it is much more likely that the act of toggling these registers will wear something else out prematurely (than the SRAM type memory cell itself).

To your particular case, correctly driving a fan/motor can significantly improve it's life time.  Over driving a fan/motor does not always make it go faster, but instead creates heat.  The heat weakens the wiring and eventually the coils will short reducing drive and eventually wearing out.  That said, the element being cooled can be damaged by excess heat so tuning things just to reduce sound may not make sense.

---

### Background details

Generally, the element is called a [Flip-Flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) with various forms. [SystemRDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemRDL) is an example as well as SystemC and others where digital engineers will model these.  In digital hardware, the flip-flops have default or reset values.  This is fixed like ROM on each chip and is not normally re-programmable, uses EEPROM technology<sup>Note1</sup> or is often configured via input lines which the hardware designer can pull them high/low with a resistor or connect them to another elements 'GPIO'.

It is analogous to 'initdata'.  Program values that aren't zero get copied from flash, disk, etc to memory at program startup.  So the flip-flops normally do not hold state over a power cycle; something else does this.

The 'Flash' technology is based off of a floating gate and uses 'quantum tunnelling' to program the floating gates.  This process is slightly destructive.  It was invented by [Fowler and Nordheim](https://www.3dincites.com/2018/02/invention-tunneling-based-flash-memory/) in 1967, but wide spread electronics industry did not start to produce them until the early 90s with NOR flash followed by NAND flash and many variants.  But the underlying physics is the same; just the digital connections are different.  So as well as this defect you are concerned about, the flash technology actually followed many hardware chips such as 68k, i386, etc.  So 'flip-flops' were well established and typically the 'register' part of the logic is not that great of a typical chip and a flip-flop uses the same logic (gates) as the rest of the chip logic.  Meaning that using flash would be an extra overhead with little benefit.

---

Some additional take-away is that the startup up and shutdown of chips is usually the most destructive time.  Often poor hardware designers do not put proper voltage supervision and some lines maybe floating with the expectation that system programs will set them immediately.  Reset events, ESD, over heating, etc will all be more harmful than just the act of writing a peripheral register.

Note 1: EEPROM typically has 100,000+ cycles.  These features are typically only used once at manufacture time to set a chip configuration for the system.  These are actually quite rare, but possible.

The MLC (multi-level) NAND flash in SSD has pathetically low cycles like 8,000 in some cases.  The SLC (single level) old school flash have 10,000+ cycles, but people demand large data formats.